# append() no funciona en Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

Tengo un código que recoge datos de una BD y los introduce en una página dinámicamente, para ello creo con jquery los elementos y etiquetas dentro de una página "en blanco" (tiene algunos datos fijos). En Chrome me funciona sin ningún problema, no da ningún tipo de error pero, cuando llego a Internet Explorer me salta lo siguiente:

> Error en tiempo de ejecución de JavaScript: El objeto no acepta la propiedad o el método 'append'

He de decir que en Chrome desde el móvil me pasa lo mismo, no puedo ver la excepción pero me da un error también y no se muestran los datos.

```
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
tr.setAttribute("id", "1234");
$("table")[0].append(tr);
```

Esas son las líneas de código donde da error, exactamente en el "append". He estado mirando pero no encuentro en ningún sitio que sea un método no compatible con IE o móvil.

No creo que sea debido a un error en otro punto del código porque, como he dicho, me funciona perfectamente en chrome, y, dado que es un código muy extenso, no veo necesario añadir más porque creo que es una pregunta más teórica, pero si se ve necesario un ejemplo más "funcional" puedo hacerlo.

**EDIT**

Añado un pequeño ejemplo sencillo que tampoco he conseguido que funcione en IE

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
var tr = document.createElement("tr");
tr.setAttribute("id", "123");
$("table").append(tr);

var td = document.createElement("td");
td.setAttribute("id", "111");
tr.append(td);

td.innerText = "Fila1";
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table></table>
```

Comment: podrias agregar el codigo completo tanto html como jquery/js , dado que le problema puede ser por algun error de tag es decir mal cerrado o abierto IE es muy sensitivo a esto, mozilla, chrome no lo es..

Comment: Intentalo asi: `$("table").append(tr);`

Comment: Eso suele ocurrir debido a otros errores, tales como: una tabla con etiqueta de apertura `<table>`, pero sin etiquita de cierre `</table>`, (o idéntica situación con `tr` o `td` de la tabla), o también debido a elementos con id repetidos, u otros elementos sin cerrar que producen un error en el DOM. Verifica que todo está correcto en ese sentido.

Comment: He comprobado todos los tags y, efectivamente, están todos cerrados, igualmente he añadido un pequeño ejemplo muy sencillo que tampoco ha llegado a funcionar en IE...

Comment: version de IE? hay ciertos temas al agregar los elementos de a uno, a veces te agrega un tbody extra. igualmente append es una funcion de jquery, para aplicarlo a un `document.createElement` tenes que "jqueryearlo" prueba `$(tr).append(td)`

Comment: o mas vanilla `tr.appendChild(td);  `

Answer (score 1):

append es una funcion de jquery, para aplicarlo a un document.createElement tenes que "jqueryearlo" onda:  `$(tr).append(td);`

o mas vanilla `tr.appendChild(td);`

te dejo tres opciones fíjate cual te funciona

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    tr.setAttribute("id", "123");
    $("table").append(tr);

    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.setAttribute("id", "111");
    tr.appendChild(td);
   
    td.innerText = "Fila1 col1";

    var td2 = document.createElement("td");
    td2.setAttribute("id", "111");
    td2.innerText = "Fila1 col2";
    $(tr).append(td2);

    

    $(tr).append($("<td>").html("Fila1 col3"));

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table></table>
```

Comment: He conseguido hacerlo con `appendChild()` el problema es que algunos funcionaban sólo con `append()` y otros no, tuve que ir uno a uno viendo qué le funcionaría... Pero muchas gracias!

Comment: suele suceder al combinar vanilla con jquery, ante la duda un `$()` siempre da pistas